# Write all my users and their attributes to a file (100K+ Users) EAV table and automation

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, batch-processing

So I have a large scale WordPress site 100K+ users.

I need to loop over each user and write some of the data that is stored in their WP_Users row and some of the metadata contained in the WP_Usermeta table.

The problem with this is that with 100K+ users this runs out of memory pretty quickly and generates 3 queries per user. You can see I have batch size and paged setup for paginating this but what I want to know is how I can recursively run this until it has finished iterating over every user. With a batch size of 500, it takes 195 pages and I cant sit there and run each batch by hitting the webpage each time. Plus it's only growing and going to get worse. How can I automate this process? Is a message queue like rabbitMQ the answer is there a quick tool for this or am I just an idiot? I wrote some javascript to hit the webpage over and over 195 times and increment the paged variable each time but its very slow and requires me to leave my machine on a specific webpage.

```
<?php
$users = get_users(array('fields' => array('ID'), 'number' => $batch_size, 'paged' => $i));
  $filetowrite = fopen($filename, 'a');

 foreach ($users as $user) {
$userdata = get_userdata( $user );

$phone_number = get_user_meta($user, 'billing_phone', true);

if (isset($userdata->first_name)) {
  $first_name = $userdata->first_name;
} else {
  $first_name = '';
}

if (empty($first_name)) {
  $first_name = get_user_meta($user, 'billing_first_name', true);
}

if (isset($userdata->last_name)) {
  $last_name = $userdata->last_name;
} else {
  $last_name = '';
}

if (empty($last_name)) {
  $last_name = get_user_meta($user, 'billing_last_name', true);
}
fwrite($filetowrite, $phone_number.','.$userdata->user_email.','.$first_name.','.$last_name.','."\n");
}

fclose($filetowrite);
```

Comment: Perhaps try writing a custom query to extract the exact data you want and then rewrite your script to run from the command line. Chunk the job into batches or a queue and hook it up to crontab to run the next batch when the first batch is complete.

Comment: Do you really need to write to a file? That makes everything a lot slower and uses more memory. You could write to a database, then make a separate program to later write from the database  to a file.

Comment: A _master_ which has an AJAX request to a PHP process page. The PHP process page checks for results and returns a status value that lets the _master_ know to continue or stop (because complete) or stop (due to error, with a status of the error and how far through the process).